# Change Woocommerce Product Categories Widget 'Title' based on Product Category

Tags: widgets, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm looking for a way to change the widget title of Woocommerce Product Categories Widget based on the category I'm viewing.

> Category 1 -----> Display Title of Widget for Category 1
>
> ```
> - Sub Category
> - Sub Category
> - Sub Category
> ```
>
> Category 2  -----> Display Title of Widget for Category 1
>
> ```
> - Sub Category
> - Sub Category
> - Sub Category
> ```

I'm working with this but can't seem to target the widget title and create the if else statement correctly.

```
function retitle_woo_category_widget() {
    // If 'Category' 1 is being viewed...
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Category 1', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        //... Remove the images
        return __('Title of Widget for Category 1');
    }
    else {
    // If 'Category' 2 is being viewed...
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Category 2', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        return __('Title of Widget for Category 2');
}

add_filter ( 'widget_title' , 'retitle_woo_category_widget');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

- Your code has syntax error `if` and `else` block are not closed!
- Also you are changing all widget title. Be specific to target only product category widget by checking for `widget ID`
- Your current code will only effect if you are viewing single product page belongs to above categories. For all other pages return `title` as it is so title will not be blank.

Example:-

```
function retitle_woo_category_widget($title, $widet_instance, $widget_id) {

    if ( $widget_id !== 'woocommerce_product_categories' )
        return $title;

    // If 'Category' 1 is being viewed...
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Category 1', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        //... Remove the images
        return __('Title of Widget for Category 1');

    // If 'Category' 2 is being viewed...
    } else if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Category 2', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        return __('Title of Widget for Category 2');
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter ( 'widget_title' , 'retitle_woo_category_widget', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the 10, 3 mean at the very end?

Comment: @thisisbolo `10` is priority of action and `3` is number of arguments to passed in callback function. Please continue reading [Parameters for add_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Parameters)

Comment: @thisisbolo If answer works for us then we accept it, [described here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if not then we let answerer know what is the problem!

Comment: I've tried these suggestions but this code doesn't produce any results.

Comment: I've tested this answer, it is working fine. Perhaps you are not sure about the question. Good Luck :)